# behavior of shadow variables in pre-allocation using PlanningPin and shadow variable

Tags: optaplanner

If a program was pre-allocated using @plannningPin when load the problem, the InverseRelationShadowVariable value does not reflect the value of the shadow variable when solve the problem.(remains empty)
Is there a recalculation function for shadow variables?
If not, is it necessary to also set the shadow variable value when pre-allocating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the warning in the docs for `@InverseRelationShadowVariable` (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html#bidirectionalVariable):

> The input planning problem of a Solver must not violate bi-directional
> relationships. If A points to B, then B must point to A. OptaPlanner
> will not violate that principle during planning, but the input must
> not violate it either.

This means that if your Planning Entity already have an `InverseRelationShadowVariable` value (because it is pre-allocated/pinned), then that value MUST also point at that entity in its `InverseRelationShadowVariable` variable.

Currently, there is no way to trigger recalculation of shadow variables in OptaPlanner. The issue that tracks this is https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1316.

Comment: Thanks a ton!
Thanks for sharing the issues tracking this.

Answer (score 1):

Since v8.35 https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1316 has been fixed. It's now possible to update a solution with

```
 SolutionManager.create(solverFactory).explain(solution)
```

This is useful in particular for pinning. Clearly it's up to the user to set planning varibles accordingly before updating the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!! I will use it in my future work.